# how to prove that this function is well defined?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am working with intervals on the real line. The interval can be of any type $[a,b],(a,b),[a,b)$ etc.

For every interval, I define the length $l(I)=b-a$.

Let A be a set of finite disjoint intervals. That is: $A= I_1 \ldots \cup I_n$.
And I define:

$l(A)=l(I_1)+\cdots+l(I_{n})$.

**Then I need to show that if  if A has another representation of finite disjoint intervals, then $l(A)$ is still the same.**

That is:

$l(I'_1)+\ldots l(I'_m)=l(I_1)+\ldots l(I_n)$

I am able to exclude the infinite case. If one of the intervals on the left side has value infinity, then one on the left side also has to have it, or else it is easy to find an element that is in:
$I'_1 \ldots \cup I'_m$, which is not in $ I_1 \ldots \cup I_n$.

**But I am struggling when all intervals have finite value.**

One idea I had is that we then close all the intervals, since this doesn't change the value. And we start at the lowest value and go forward, it is easy to convince yourself that the values must be the same, but it is not a very mathematical proof.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Why exclude the infinite case? You could show that they're a $\sigma$-algebra, take $(a,b)=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \ [a+\frac{1}{n}, b-\frac{1}{n}]$. Your given $l$ is an outer measure.